# Decorate webclient response using reactive context

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to pass a parameter through the webClient context to understand how the reactive context works.

```
    .post()
    .uri(uri)
    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.putAll(headers))
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(payload))
    .exchange()
    .flatMap( s -> Mono.subscriberContext()
        .map( ctx -> {
            System.out.println(“SubscriberContext1 " + ctx.getOrDefault("test", "DefaultValue”));
            return s;
        }))
    .flatMap(resp -> {
         return resp
            .bodyToMono(Object.class)
            .defaultIfEmpty(new HashMap<>())
            .map(body -> {
                //I would like to access the context variable here
                return doSomething(body, contextVariable);
            });})
    .flatMap( s -> Mono.subscriberContext()
        .map( ctx -> {
            System.out.println("SubscriberContext2” + ctx.getOrDefault("test", "DefaultValue”));
            return s;
        }))
    .subscriberContext(ctx -> {
        System.out.println("WRITE TEST");
        ctx.put("test", "test");
        return ctx;
    });
```

This prints out:

```
WRITE TEST
SubscriberContext1 DefaultValue
SubscriberContext2 DefaultValue
```

I'd expect it to be:

```
WRITE TEST
SubscriberContext1 test
SubscriberContext2 test
```

Why is the context variable not accessible within the flatMap?

Comment: try to put `ctx.put("test", "test");` in first `flatMap`

Comment: That also doesn't do the trick, but made me realise what's the problem. 
ctx.put creates a brand new context.
Changing subscriber context to return it (return ctx.put("test", "test");) solves the problem.

Comment: Wow that's awesome

Answer (score 0):

ctx.put creates a new context. Changing the code to:

```
 .subscriberContext(ctx -> {
        System.out.println("WRITE TEST");
        return ctx.put("test", "test");

    });
```

solves it.